# PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class not logging IPN results

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Micah Carrick's PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class and have code in paypal.class.php as:

```
   function __construct() {
      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.
      $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      $this->last_error = '';
      $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
      $this->ipn_log = true; 
      $this->ipn_response = '';
```

However, this file is not being created. Do I need to do something special to get it to work?

If I need to set permissions, do I set permissions on this or the calling php script (which includes the above file)?

Comment: Try specifying a full path. You are aware that the leading `.` will hide the file?

Comment: @Pekka - what's the emoticon for being terribly embarrassed!

Comment: hahaha! Good question. :) If that fixed it, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the dot in `.ipn_results.log` will hide the file on Unix/Linux systems. You probably mean

```
$this->ipn_log_file = './ipn_results.log';
```

but it is preferable to specify a full path here to avoid confusion.